# System Error 183 when opening an RStudio Project

Tags: r, windows, azure, rstudio

When trying to open an RStudio Project (a .Rproj file), an error window pops up that states:

> Project '/project.Rproj' could not be opened: unable to initialize project - system error 183 (Cannot create a file when that file already exists)

The operating system is a Windows Server 2019, and the folder is just attached storage on Azure.

The issue surfaced after permissions across the directory were changed. Access was originally granted to the folder in which the .Rproj file lives, and then were reset again across several directories, including this one. But the user account trying to access specifically has full access to the folder containing the .Rproj file.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the problem here is not the .Rproj file itself, or the permissions associated with the .Rproj file and folders. The real issue was the hidden [.Rproj.user](https://www.uvm.edu/%7Etdonovan/RforFledglings/projects.html) folder. This directory already existed, and when the .Rproj file was opened, it was trying to create the directory.

The issue is solved by simply deleting the .Rproj.user directory. Note - this folder is used to store user specific information about their RStudio session, so they can pick up where they left off when they open the file - so this session information will be lost.